# How to change the value of a select based on a previous select selection when the value has more than one word

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I apologize for the redundant title.

Basically I have two selects, the first select 'updates' the second select when any option is selected.

The problem comes when any of the options contains more than one word. For example: `dark red`.

I would like to modify the snippet attached here so that it works for both cases.

Restrictions: I cannot modify the `value` attribute, if so, the form will not work properly.

I would like to do it with another attribute like `id` but I have tried and I couldn't make it work.

The attached snippet works with `<option value="dark_red">` but I can not do that, is there any option to make it work with (for example) `<option id="dark_red">` instead of `value`?

```js
var fruit = $("[name=fruit] option").detach()
$("[name=color]").change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val()
  $("[name=fruit] option").detach()
  fruit.filter("." + val).clone().appendTo("[name=fruit]")
}).change()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple name=color>
<option selected>green</option>
<option>red</option>
<option value="dark_red">dark red</option>
<option>yellow</option>
</select>
<select multiple name=fruit>
<option class=green>Grapes</option>
<option class=green>Watermelon</option>
<option class="red green">Apples</option>
<option class="dark_red red">Cherries</option>
<option class="green yellow">Bananas</option>
<option class=yellow>Lemons</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace spaces in the `val` with an underscore.

```js
var fruit = $("[name=fruit] option").detach()
$("[name=color]").change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val().replace(/\s/g, "_");
  $("[name=fruit] option").detach()
  fruit.filter("." + val).clone().appendTo("[name=fruit]")
}).change()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name=color>
  <option>Select a color</option>
  <option>green</option>
  <option>red</option>
  <option>dark red</option>
  <option>yellow</option>
  <option>super dark blue</option>
</select>
<select name=fruit>
  <option class=green>Grapes</option>
  <option class=green>Watermelon</option>
  <option class="red green">Apples</option>
  <option class="dark_red red">Cherries</option>
  <option class="green yellow">Bananas</option>
  <option class=yellow>Lemons</option>
  <option class=super_dark_blue>Mode</option>
  <option class=super_dark_blue>Blueberries</option>
</select>
```

If you need multiple inputs, you can do something like this:

```js
const fruit = $("[name=fruit] option").detach();
$("[name=color]").change(function () {
  // detach all fruits
  $("[name=fruit] option").detach();

  // loop through all values
  const values = $(this).val(),
    addedValues = [];
     
  values.forEach(val => {
    val = val.replace(/\s/g, "_");
    
    // checking for duplicates
    const fruitMatch = Array.from(
      fruit.filter("." + val)
    ).filter(e => {
      return !addedValues.find(v => {
        return Array.from(e.classList).includes(v)
      });
    });
    addedValues.push(val);
    
    // append (if new)!
    $(fruitMatch).clone().appendTo("[name=fruit]");
  });
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple name=color>
  <option selected>green</option>
  <option>red</option>
  <option>dark red</option>
  <option>yellow</option>
  <option>super dark blue</option>
</select>
<select multiple name=fruit>
  <option class=green>Grapes</option>
  <option class=green>Watermelon</option>
  <option class="red green">Apples</option>
  <option class="dark_red red">Cherries</option>
  <option class="green yellow">Bananas</option>
  <option class=yellow>Lemons</option>
  <option class=super_dark_blue>Mode</option>
  <option class=super_dark_blue>Blueberries</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I edited my question. I need the selects to be 'multiple' and by default green will be selected. For some reason it does not work with your answer and I can't understand why. Any idea?

Comment: When using multiple, `val()` returns an array of strings, so `val().replace()` would not work

Comment: Yeah I just realized that too, any ideas? I'm a stuck here.

Comment: I added a second snippet for multiple support. It's a bit more complicated, but it's basically, looping through each value and replacing with underscores

Comment: Is there any way to allow just one input? I know it's a 'multiple' and the main purpose is to allow multiple selections but I just want one input and keep this appearance.

Comment: You can go with the first snippet and just add `[0]` between `val()` and `.replace()` (gets the first value)